# Is there a way to sort by unanswered, newest, and my tags?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, sorting

Since unanswered looks like this:

`http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest`

I was curious if there is a way to do something like what you would think the url:

`http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=newest+mytags`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20is%3aq%20answers%3a0
```

This will find you the newest (`tab=newest`) questions (`is:q`) in your tags (`intags:mine`) with no answers (`answers:0`). As Animuson has already pointed out, this is questions with zero answers, rather than no *upvoted* answers per the Unanswered list.

For more information see https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wonder if when I proposed this question some of these features weren't yet available. It just seems so easy!

Answer (score 5):

First, compose a search. Say you like questions in the [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) tag. Search for `[algorithm]` and you get this URL:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm
```

If you look at the “Advanced Search Tips”, you’ll find you can use `answers:0` in your query to limit it to unanswered questions. Then you get this URL:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Balgorithm%5D+answers%3A0
```

And when you’re on that page, there’s a newest tab, leading you finally to

```
https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5balgorithm%5d%20answers%3a0
```

And that’s your page!

Comment: Technically wouldn't yield the same results, as the results in the Unanswered page would include questions with no *upvoted* answers. But if the OP only wants questions with absolutely no answers, this works great.