# How to stroll new questions list

Tags: support, questions, sorting, question-lists

Is it possible to stroll through [new questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest) **without** new questions updating the cache (contrary to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292399/7926064)) so that pagination does not show the same questions again (because they were pushed to a later page).

**Page 1**
[image]

**Page 2**
[image]

One workaround i can think of is to increase the questions per page, but it seems 50 is the limit, even when using the [Search API](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) (e.g. `&pagesize=100`).

Another approach would be, to reduce the chance of a new question while strolling, again with the Search API like [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294500/7926064). Now i might miss an interesting question that i dont have a tag for or that was mis-tagged.

How do i achieve the goal: find new unanswered questions exactly once in chronological order without limiting the search scope?

Comment: One way this *could* be implemented, is to have a parameter to the search API with the ID of the last post that was seen, indicating that results "after that" should be returned. An alternative pagination, so to say. That does assume that the order of search results is consistent.

Comment: Don't think so. I've always used a workaround where I open all the pages at once (e.g. a bookmark folder with links to page one, two, three, etc to whatever max I want) or I ctrl-click the buttons on the bottom to open the pages in new tabs.  Not perfect, but it works well enough.

Comment: Is that really worth it, though? @Will

Comment: IMO 50 questions per pages is enough to see at least 40 NEW questions per page strolled. Is it really this annoying to see a couple of questions twice ?

Comment: This is *exactly* the sort of thing that the new invention of a tab-based browser is for: Open the links to the questions you want to see in new tabs (often with just a middle-click, but what it really takes depends on OS/browser/settings), then just switch back to the tab with the question list. That way your list of questions doesn't update, until you request it to do so by reloading the page.  You can also load multiple pages of the question list in different tabs, which will have the same pagination, as long as you open them at nearly the same time (e.g from a bookmark set).

Comment: @AntoinePelletier if it can be avoided, yes. If its the same questions over and over again (because new questions pour in as i swich to page 3 and so on), yes.

Comment: @Makyen using workarounds is possible, but "opening multiple tabs at nearly the same time" is not very convenient. Maybe an infinity view for the questions lists (user enabled) would be a good solution. You were right about the link, thanks, just updated the question.